# In Android Studio (flutter app), how to remove/fix this error(in picture) message in emulator selection?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

[Open Android Emulator: INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Temp\Android Emulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 11216]
[image]

I have tried following: restarted the computer, cleared the emulator data & created new instance of the emulator, but didn't work. I am  using windows 11 and Android Studio Iguana.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android emulator command always log an error (Storing crashdata, detection is enabled for process...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78107825/android-emulator-command-always-log-an-error-storing-crashdata-detection-is-en)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler, no.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78111618/4373661

Comment: @AnupBarua It's probably a new IDE with an old emulator.  Update the emulator to `32.1.15` and then create a new AVD image: https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Comment: in sdk tools, i see the Android Emulator version is  34.1.19